# LED-flash during powerup with my ZCD/Triac-circuit

Tags: led, oscilloscope, flash, triac, zero-crossing

Friends,
I've made a ZDC-circut to dim my 230VAC LED-chip. It works fine except for a short, flashy, annoying blink when powered up!! It happens about 8/10 times when I switch the power on/off. Any1 else had this issue before?
Below is my connection diagram:

[image: Connection diagram for the 230VAC ZCD/Triac-circut]

I wish i could have posted a video of the flash, but here is my scop-screen triggered by a powerup flash:

[image: Scop triggered by flash]

Scoop-screen during dimming, approx 20% of max:

[image: Dimming 20% of max]

Scoop-screen during dimming, approx 90% of max:

[image: Dimming 90% of max]

I just measured my zerocross-pulses on D2, its not stable on 10ms. It changes constantly between 8-13 ms, so i have to look into the ZCD-part of the circut. Anyway, if someone had this issue before any tips would be highly appriciated =)

[image: Zerocross-pulses]

Comment: Your LED is actually an LED driver+ LED?

Comment: No, it`s a 230VAC LED:
https://www.amazon.com/Bulbs-Integrated-Spotlight-Floodlight-Aluminum/dp/B09NBKBH9P

Comment: Thanks, please edit that into the question.

Comment: Yep, i have updated the text 